# How to stop the hidden __MACOSX folder from being created when compressing files/folders in Finder

Tags: mac, folders, zip

When compressing files/folders in Finder, via the context menu, i.e. select the files/folders then right-click and select Compress ..., a hidden folder named __MACOSX is created within the zip archive.

How can the hidden folder named __MACOSX not be created within the zip archive?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/288568/edit) your question to clarify what is actually happening. Specifically, can you expand on what you mean by a hidden folder being created? Is this located within the archive? Or do you mean you get nothing but an empty folder (i.e. nothing is being archived)? Or something else?

Comment: By default, files/folders compressed in Finder are proceeded using Archive Utility and this app does not have the setting preferences to keep meta-data from bring added to the archive. You'll have to use a third-party solution or other macOS built-in utilities/methods, i.e. using command line utilities like `ditto`, `zip` or creating an Automator Service to perform the actions necessary to achieve the goal, etc.

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using info from the other answer, here's an **Automator Service**<sup>1</sup> that becomes available in **Finder** to delete the "__MACOSX" *meta-data* folder from a zip archive file.

**To Create the Service:**

1. Open **Automator** and select: **File** > **New** > **Service**
2. Set **Service receives selected** to **files or folders** and **in** to **Finder**.
3. Add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*, setting **Shell:** to **/bin/bash** and **Pass input:** to **as arguments** while replacing the default *code* with the following *code*:

   ```
   for f in "$@"; do
       if [[ ${f##*.} =~ ^[zZ][iI][pP]$ ]]; then
           zip -d "$f" "__MACOSX*"
       fi
   done
   afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Purr.aiff
   ```

   - What the *code* does: It checks that each file passed to the service has a zip extension, regardless of case, and if it has a zip extension, and if "__MACOSX" exists within the zip archive, deletes the "__MACOSX" *meta-data folder* from the zip archive.
   - `${f##*.}` gets the file extension, `=~` tests the *regex*, and the `^[zZ][iI][pP]$` *regex* matches any case combination of each letter within the *square braces* while `^` asserts position at start of the string and `$` asserts position at the end of the string. So it only matches `zip` in any case combination of those letters.
   - Note: The last line of the *code* is optional, just to let you know the service completed, and can be changed to a different sound or omitted if you prefer not to be notified by sound upon completion.
4. Save the **Service** as, e.g.,: **Delete '__MACOSX' from Zip Archive**

<sub><sup>1</sup> In **macOS Mojave**, and later, an **Automator** *Service* is called a *Quick Action*. There are also other minor nomenclature differences but they should be more obvious when comparing them to pre-macOS Mojave Automator workflows.</sub>

**To Use the Service:**

In **Finder**, or on the **Desktop** if the zip archive is located there, select the zip archive(s), then **right-click** and select **Delete '__MACOSX' from Zip Archive** from the context menu or under **Services** on the context menu, or from **Services** on the **Finder** *menu* as appropriate.

The image of the *service* in **Automator**, below, is from OS X 10.8.6, however, it was tested under macOS 10.12.5 and works there as well.

[image: Automator Service]

Comment: Well done. Would you mind me making an edit to explain why these folders properly exist when you encode HFS+ files or speculations that be better as it’s own answer?

Comment: @bmike, Not at all, sounds like value added... thanks.

Comment: Its Great. Thank you ii work.
is it possible that service will compress and delete the files. 
all in one click?

Comment: Awesome solution! The steps have slightly changed with the newer versions of MacOS:

1. Open Automator and select: File > New
2. Select "Quick Action"
3. Set: Workflow receives current to "files or folders" and in: Finder.app.

Answer (score 8):

From [WP Guru - How to remove __MACOSX from zip archives](https://wpguru.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-remove-__macosx-from-zip-archives/)

> First, create your ZIP via the finder – like you always do. Next, open
>   Terminal and cd into the directory where your ZIP file is located. If
>   it’s a long path, just type “cd “, then drag the folder into Terminal
>   (less typing is always good).
>
> Now type the following:
>
> `zip -d your-archive.zip "__MACOSX*"`
>
> And that should do it. This
>   command (zip) will remove everything (-d) starting with __MACOSX from
>   your ZIP file (your-archive.zip).
>
> To verify, type the following:
>
> `unzip -l your-archive.zip`
>
> This will simply list the contents of
>   your-archive.zip.

If you're not comfortable with Terminal, [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com) has an option to do this for you, but it's $25.

Comment: I would like to totally disable this option.

Comment: I doubt that's possible. The data is there for the OS to be able to correctly re-merge metadata that cannot be carried in the files otherwise.

Comment: I think MacOS is great, but I do not see how a zip file with a verifiable magic number should require any OS-specific meta data.

Comment: @Rob - Because other disk formats & OSes will otherwise just lose it, as already explained.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not sure I understand. The files are not "lost" by other operating systems. For example, if you need to validate an archive contains a specific set of files and no others in linux, these files will show up and have to be excluded or ignored.  Since they can be faked, they could even act as a vehicle for malware data.

Comment: The data would be lost if the Mac hadn't already split it out. It's the equivalent of trying to get FAT to support unix file perms… not gonna happen.

Comment: This is meta data specific to macos though. It is not relevant to the data contained in the the archive. I would not expect FAT to support unix file perms, and I wouldn't want unix to attach additional meta any time I create an archive just so when they are brought back unix can properly set the perms again. MacOS seems to presume the meta is vital and benign and I disagree.

Comment: You can disagree all you like, but if a Mac user ever wants that file back, they'd like the metadata too, no doubt. You find it inconvenient because you have an OS that can't make use of it. Why deny it to others who may? You can try the same with media files on Windows, with it's irritating 'streams' info, which it cannot transfer to anything other than NTFS… so it tells you every single time that it will delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Like user3439894 said, try third-party solution.  I'm using free application Keka with success, long term:

http://www.kekaosx.com/en/

Configure in Keka preferences to not create mac-specific files in archives. It can also be used via the context menu (after adding "Compress with Keka.workflow" to your "~/Library/Services" folder), see the link at the bottom left of their website.